# How to mockup a realistic cloth tag with a custom shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, texture, mockup, shadows

Making a cloth label mockup with any shape I want, while still looking decently realistic, would be a dream come true.

For example, I have an initial mockup like this

[image]

If I want my label to be star shaped I place it in a smart vector then save it and boom. The cloth tag its updated to a star shape while still looking somewhat realistic (higlights, shadows, textures, extrude width, extrude shadows, etc). Ends up looking like this

[image]

The problem is that I can't find free nor premium mockups that are able to do that. All available cloth label mockups are square.

Is this possible to create in photosop?

Comment: Yesd but why bother when you can render the layers in a 3d app.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not sure if my pc can handle 3D rendering. Besides I have cero expertise in the topic, I find it intimidating. Anyhow, what's a recommended place to start?

Comment: The image example you posted looks like an actual photograph.

Comment: Cut a piece of cloth in, you know, *real life*.. photograph it... Even an iPhone can take a decent photo which can be post processed. (Actually quite funny that the iPhone camera is now *better* than all the early, thousands-of-dollars, 8MP digital cameras)

Comment: hmm.. my first dedicated digital camera was a whole 1MP ;) As to whether any modern computer can 'handle 3D rendering' I first did that in the mid 90s. Admittedly we did often have to leave it running over the weekend, but it worked.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah any computer built after 2003 is probably powerfull enough

Comment: @Scott that's quite usefull if I can't find a propper background, or you mean to print the label and photograph it too?

Comment: Nah.. just the cloth, you can do the actual label in Photoshop.. place it on a white sheet and photograph it. That way you get lighting/shadows that are all realistic (cuz they're real `:)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely possible in Photoshop.  If your label is a Smart Object, then inside the smart object you can put different shapes of labels inside a group, and clip the group to a paper texture. So it's just a matter of hiding the shape you don't want. Then update the Smart Object.  You may even be able to modify an existing mockup if you have one, so it's arranged similarly.

For example. This is just a quick mockup I threw together using some basic textures found online.

[image]
Click on image to see larger

Comment: Thank you so much! I will keep coming back to that gif. Super usful reference!

Answer (score 5):

An answer with several parts:

---

The truth is that if you want real flexibility in making mockups you need to learn a 3D program.

Use Blender https://www.blender.org/ that is free, very powerful.

If your computer is slow, and I mean, really slow, (Pentium) you can download a legacy version. https://download.blender.org/release/ compare the date of release to the year you bought your computer. Do not go below version 2.5. That is ancient.

---

Look for tutorials on youtube on:

1. Cloth simulation
2. Cloth texture
3. Importing shapes
4. Texturing
5. Colisions
6. Light and Render

It is not very hard, but it takes some time. The advantage, besides having total control on your mockup is that the next design will take you just a couple of minutes to do, because you just need to replace the textures.

[image]

---

But if you are still intimidated, just make a simpler mockup that you can control.

[image]

[image]

Here are the source images:

- https://pixabay.com/es/photos/papel-%c3%a1lbum-de-recortes-textura-1914901/
- https://pixabay.com/es/photos/textil-brown-antecedentes-tela-1866908/
- https://www.pexels.com/photo/gray-notebook-beside-tealight-candle-705670/
- https://www.pexels.com/photo/blue-textile-235525/

But with a simpler setup you can, not only change the shape of the tag, but the texture and the cloth below. You can add perspective if you want.

[image]

---

I also agree with @Scott, the art of **making real-life dummies** is forgotten. It would be interesting to print a test in real life. This is especially true to things that will be, not only printed, but also cut. **It will give you a real idea of the structure**, and how sturdy the label will be. I suppose the star is only an example. But it is not a good structure to be used as a label.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time with well done examples! I will start considering blender, thogh I'm not sure how it will perform, since rendering 3D in Photoshop was pretty slow. (I have a Ryzen 5 with AMD Radeon Vega 8, 8Bg RAM)
That simpler mockup is also a good reference. And yes, the star it's an example, I do a agree that it wouldn't be a practical solution.

Comment: That is more than enough. You will be fine with the newest version of Blender.

Comment: Hi Rafael! I was having a hard time picking what answer to mark as the problem solving one. Albeit yours adds a lot of value I think I'm picking Billy Kerrs answer, since he adresses how to solve the problem in photoshop with more detail. Again, thanks for your time!

Comment: You are wellcome! :)